# Adding Trendline on Plotly Scatterplot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have three different data columns. The columns have been converted to simplify the question.

```
size = [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
time = [228.64, 28.8, 3.88, 0.47, 439.72,54.2, 6.65, 0.77, 808.67, 103.53, 12.3, 1.79]
error = [0.0, 0.53, 0.28, 2.03, 0.0, 0.09, 0.29, 2.22, 0.0, 0.04, 0.35, 0.11]
```

I am trying to plot them using a scatter plot. X-axis will contain the size and Y-axis will contain time and error.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=size, y=time, name="Time", mode = "markers", marker_symbol=3, marker_size = 10, marker_color = "red"),
    secondary_y=False)


fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=size, y=error, mode = "markers",name="Error", marker_symbol=14,marker_size = 10, marker_color = "black")), 
    secondary_y=True)

fig.show()
```

I want to add trendlines:

exponential/logarithmic trendline for size vs time

linear trendline for size vs error  

Is there a built-in function of doing that?  

  
I am getting the following graph:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think Plotly Express has built-in support for some trendlines:https://plotly.com/python/linear-fits/

But not 'plain' Plotly. But it is not difficult to add them by hand. See the few lines I added to calculate the fitted values

```
size = [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
time = [228.64, 28.8, 3.88, 0.47, 439.72,54.2, 6.65, 0.77, 808.67, 103.53, 12.3, 1.79]
error = [0.0, 0.53, 0.28, 2.03, 0.0, 0.09, 0.29, 2.22, 0.0, 0.04, 0.35, 0.11]

import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

err_size_regr = LinearRegression()
err_size_res = err_size_regr.fit(np.array(size).reshape(-1,1), np.array(error))
err_fit = err_size_regr.predict(np.array(size).reshape(-1,1))

time_size_regr = LinearRegression()
time_size_res = err_size_regr.fit(np.array(size).reshape(-1,1), np.log(np.array(time)))
time_fit = np.exp(time_size_res.predict(np.array(size).reshape(-1,1)))


import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=size, y=time, name="Time", mode = "markers", marker_symbol=3, marker_color = "red"),
    secondary_y=False)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=size, y=time_fit, mode = "markers",name="Time fit", marker_symbol=3, marker_color = "blueviolet"), 
    secondary_y=False)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=size, y=error, mode = "markers",name="Error", marker_symbol=14,marker_color = "green"), 
    secondary_y=True)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=size, y=err_fit, mode = "lines",name="Error fit", marker_color = "lightgreen"), 
    secondary_y=True)

fig.show()
```

output (sorry I changed your colours to see the result better)

[image: plot with fits]